# Costs associated with Data Analysis (data cleaning) on the cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I am data analyst. My company is moving all data science to a cloud provider (it could be Azure, GCP,AWS). All the data science programming tools like Jupyter notebook will be installed on the cloud environment (there will be no local installations of Python, or Jupyter Notebooks on the laptop).

For most of my work, I will be reading/ingesting relational database tables directly from an on-premise Database. Also most of my data analysis work does not require any GPU instances for data processing. Sometimes, I also do simple research or experimentation data analysis programming such as data cleaning using Jupyter notebooks without the need for usage of GPU instances.

I would like to find out if it would be possible to do such activities without incurring any pay-per-use costs or unnecessary expenses for my company on their data science cloud computing platform given that none of my tasks utilize GPUs?  Please advise, thank you.

***EDIT Note:*** It is difficult to work & develop locally with Jupyter on my company PC because I do not have full permissions to install Python packages(usually this has to be requested for approval, which is very painful and takes a very long time).

Comment: The answer to this is use-cases specific. And really, your company is moving to the cloud, and has no idea how much it will cost?

Comment: I do not have information about the costs, it is with the IT department. My question is around using something like Jupyter notebooks. If it is a pay-per-use cloud environment, I'd like to find out if I get charged for just opening a Jupyter notebook (non-GPU) instance.

Comment: Yes, you pay for the instances. GPU instances will cost more, then non-GPU ones. Cloud environment is not free. You always have to pay for compute resources and storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter Notebook can be installed in the cloud, but also on prem and on your workstation. You pay either resource in the cloud, on prem, or your worstation.

Of course, if you add large disk, GPUs, CPUs, memory, it costs more! The problem isn't the cost, it is more where do you want to run your notebook?

---

I think, there is a bad alternative. With Colab you have free Jupyter Notebook instance. But, AFAIK, it's not private, it's public instances and if you work for your company, you can have data leakage. (Not sure, to validate, but it's not a recommended solution in any case)

---

**EDIT 1**

Considering your latest comment, I wondering if you need a jupyter notebook to run your code.

Indeed, Jupyter is simply and IDE: you could create your script, even this one that need GPU locally, and to run it on production data on Compute Engine that you provision only for the process. At the end of the script destroy the VM. No Jupyter notebook environment for that, no?

---

**EDIT 2**

Thanks to your note, I understand that developing locally isn't an option. In this case, I recommend you to use a managed Jupyter Notebook solution. You can provision this VM on Google Cloud if you want, you can also have different VM, with or without GPU.

The principle is the same: when you stop to work with your instance, stop it. You will only pay for the storage (the disk) when the instance is down.

And the dev principle can be the same: use a small CPU/GPU for your dev, and when you have to process big data, run your script on a powerful VM. Because you pay only when the VM is running, you can optimize cost like that.

Comment: I proposed something different. use jupyter locally only for defining the script, and then a VM to run it in production.

Comment: Thanks Gui. I made a 'Edit Note' above to my question. This is the main challenge I have, so not sure what is a good workaround or solution. Your insights appreciated.

Comment: Thank you Gui. So if I understand , 1) Kill instance when not working, so that I am only billed for data storage. 2) when doing experiment dev work where GPU is not needed, then use a small CPU (which is much cheaper). Did I interpret correctly? Just to add, I might have the opportunity to lead a small team of junior analysts. Would there be any admin type of options on GCP so that I can manage settings on the VM to ensure they follow 'best practices' to optimize cost? Maybe have 2 'pre-defined' VMs (one for dev, one for big datasets)? I am wondering if Anaconda Enterprise is an option.

Comment: Yes, you interpret correctly. I don't know Anaconda Entreprise. To manage the VMs, there is different option, You can schedule the VMs, you can find solution on the internet to stop and start automatically the VM (with Cloud Scheduler for instance),... There isn't automatic tool on Google Cloud to do that, you need tooling on your side.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Guillaume's answer, if you want to keep track or to plan ahead if there are cost that will occur while using instances. You can use Google Cloud Platform's Pricing calculator:

https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator?hl=en

With this, you can can choose what product do you're interested to, what kind of components do want in your set-up (e.g. how many RAM, capacity of your storage space, CPU)in case you choose to use `GCP Compute Engine`, choose what location you are and check if that location price suits your company's budget.

If you want to have more information regarding Google Cloud Platform pricing, you can check out this link:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/all-pricing#compute-optimized_machine_types

Comment: Thanks Bryan. As I commented below to Gui, I might have the opportunity to lead a small team of junior analysts and enquired to him about any possible options in GCP (e.g., blocks, constraints) around ensuring that the juniors are limited in terms of when they can use GPUs, etc unless given permission to do so. If they have free reign, things can get expensive and out of control. I'm looking for an admin sort of option.